# How am I supposed to release an imbedded Core Foundation object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, xcode4.6

This is the code:

```
- (void) drawToday  {

int x;
int y;
int day;
CFGregorianDate today = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(currentTime, CFTimeZoneCopyDefault());

if(today.month == currentMonthDate.month && today.year==currentMonthDate.year)  {
    int swidth = self.frame.size.width / 7;
    int weekday=[self getMonthWeekday:currentMonthDate];
    day = today.day + weekday - 2;
    x = day % 7;
    y = day / 7;
```

It's complaining about this:  **CFTimeZoneCopyDefault()** saying

> *Call to function 'CFTimeZoneCopyDefault' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count* **and** *Object leaked: allocated object is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1*

How am I supposed to cure this (i.e. release the embedded object)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally:

```
CFTimeZoneRef tzref = CFTimeZoneCopySystem();
CFGregorianDate today = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate(currentTime, tzref);
CFRelease( tzref);
```

Comment: Sometimes it's just one of those days :-)